# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in EasyPHP-DevServer

Tags: php, mysql-error-1064

```
<?php 
    $resultset=array();
    $arr = array("id"   => 1,"name" => 'name',"email" => 'a@gmail.com');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);// its working 
    if($arr === FALSE) 
    { 
        die(mysql_error());//TODO: better error handling
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($arr))// not working
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo $id;
        exit;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Write your code inside {} so it will be readable.

Comment: The argument to `mysqli_fetch_array()` must be the result of calling `mysqli_query()`. `$arr` is an array, not a mysqli result.

Comment: You have no SQL query anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Saral What should it be a duplicate of? It's not the usual problem of giving a boolean because the query got an error.

Comment: Your code is missing a quote in `echo <pre>";`

Comment: You also have `if ($arr === FALSE)` in a comment. Is that intentional, or did your code get wrapped when you posted it here? Please fix the formatting.

Comment: @Saral Please provide a link to the duplicate.

Comment: There's far too much wrong here. First, we don't know if you connected to the database and which MySQL API was used for it. Far as I can see here, you're also mixing different APIs, which you can't do.

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you the error because `mysqli_fetch_array()` requires the first parameter as the result set identifier returned by `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_store_result()` or `mysqli_use_result()`:

You first need proper credentials to connect to the MySQL database. I prefer to make constants as they are secure this way. Then connect to MySQL:

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'username');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'sitename');
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

The best way is to put the above code in a separate PHP file so that you can include it whenever you need to connect to MySQL instead of writing this code in each script as this is the most important code and will be reused multiple times.

And after that you can fetch each record.

```
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
if($r){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        //Your code
    } 
}else { 
    echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '</p>';
}
 mysqli_free_result($r);
```

The PHP manual for `mysqli_fetch_array()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

The `mysqli_fetch_array()` takes an optional second parameter specifying what type of array should be returned. The optional second argument can be `MYSQLI_BOTH`, `MYSQLI_NUM` or `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.

The `MYSQLI_BOTH` is the default. The `MYSQLI_NUM` is relatively faster but I prefer `MYSQLI_ASSOC` most of the time because it works even if the query changes.

**Warning**

You are using both `mysql` and `mysqli`. The `mysql` extension is deprecated and `mysqli` should be used.

Having said that you should always use prepared statements. Prepared statements are faster, safer and help to get rid of a ton of problems.

Comment: You left out the fact that they're mixing different MySQL APIs.

Comment: I'm talking about this line `die(mysql_error());`. That's mysql_ and the OP has some mysqli_ function shown. What they didn't show us is the connection used for it, or if they even connected in the first place. That question is way too unclear to solve, not in its present state anyway.

Comment: You deleted the comment I was responding to ^

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I got it after the comment and I thought I should delete it and update the answer. Thank you for notifying me.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Should I update the answer? So tired of cycling today.

Comment: It would help, sure. Just in case and if you want to do this, would be to include a connection method using the mysqli_ api. That way if what they're using wasn't that or did not connect, it would show them the proper syntax. That way they end up with a full method.